# Vector is pointing to uninitialized bytes when used in recvfrom call

Tags: c++, linux, vector, udp, initialization

In a function that I am writing I am trying to return a pointer to a vector of unsigned chars.  The relevant code is below.

```
std::vector<unsigned char> *ret = new std::vector<unsigned char>(buffSize,'0');
//Due to suggestions...
int n = recvfrom(fd_, ret, buffSize, &recvAddress, &sockSize);
//Forgot to include this in the original
ret->resize(n);
// display chars somehow just for testing
for(std::vector<unsigned char>::iterator it=ret->begin(); it<ret->end();it++)
{
    std::cout<<*it;
}
std::cout<<std::endl;
...
return ret;
```

When I run this through valgrind I get errors talking about how the buffer in recvfrom is pointing to uninitialized bytes.  I've narrowed this down to the vector since I swapped it out for an unsigned char array and everything works fine.  Any suggestions?

Edit 1:  Fixed some of the code, was doing this from memory/notes with a problem that I was having at work.  The reason I started to use valgrind was that I was getting a segmentation fault at that spot.  I will double check what I was doing tomorrow.

Comment: Please post real code using _cut and paste_. This obviously won't compile: `it->end()` .

Comment: The commented code is wrong, `ret` is *not* equivalent to `&((*ret)[0])`. The second one works (and actually points to the vector's buffer) because `operator[]` is overloaded.

Comment: BTW - your comment that passing ret as a parameter to recvfrom will work is incorrect.  That will start overwriting the vector's fields with arbitrary data received over the network.  That actually might be the culprit.

Comment: In the end, the problem is of course because the code uses a pointer to a vector (`std::vector<unsigned char> *`). This is rarely needed, and the bug wouldn't have happened if the vector were declared as `std::vector<unsigned char> ret(buffSize,'0');`

Comment: @MSalters So you always create all your objects on the stack rather than the heap?

Comment: Objects which have function scope, such as this, yes. Always. Most other vectors in my program are class members, and again there I don't use pointers to vectors. (I might allocate the containing object on the heap, though).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This line is wrong:

```
int n = recvfrom(fd_, ret, buffSize, &recvAddress, &sockSize);
```

It should be:

```
int n = recvfrom(fd_, &(*ret)[0], buffSize, 0, &recvAddress, &sockSize);
```

You're reading data directly onto the `std::vector` data structure, which is typically 3 pointers (beginning, end, and end-of-storage).  So, you're overwriting those 3 pointers with data received over the socket, and then you're overwriting random memory after the vector.  The compiler doesn't complain because any pointer type (`std::vector<char> *` in this case) is implicitly convertible to a `void*` (the second parameter to `recvfrom`).

You of course want to read data into the buffer pointed to by the vector, which is obtained by taking the address of its first element, namely `&(*ret)[0]`.  We have to add the awkward parentheses because brackets `[]` have higher operator precedence than the unary dereferencing operator `*`.

(Also note that you're missing the `flags` parameter to `recvfrom()` -- I'm assuming that was just a transcription error when writing this question, and I've now set that to `0` here.)

Comment: Well, isn't your corrected line wrong too, since it is missing a (zero) flags argument after buffSize?

Comment: @PatchyFog: Technically yes, but that's unrelated to the issue at hand; OP's original post was missing it as well.  In any case, that's fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

Only bytes up to `n` were written by `recvfrom()` but you are reading the entire buffer as allocated.  I'm not sure valgrind is really that clever, though.

Comment: But the entire allocated buffer of the vector has been initialized with `'0'` anyway?